# How can I send a .bat file command to another IP address?

Tags: cmd, network-programming

For the particular task I'm doing I am trying to run a .bat file from my computer, but I want the command to execute on another computer. For example I have a .bat file that writes the ipconfig command to a text file. The code for said file looks like this:

```
@echo off
REM Name: ipconfig.bat
ipconfig /all > a.txt
@pause
```

Now is when the question I have comes into play; I want to run this .bat file on another computer in my network. So I have written the following .bat file to attempt this:

```
@echo off
REM Name: SendIpconfig.bat
REM The User variable represents where I tried to enter the I.P address for my laptop.
Set /p n=User:
call ipconfig.bat > %User%
@pause
```

I have also tried making the file using a `|` instead of a `>` when I try to preform my call statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just run something on a different computer, there has to be some utility on the remote machine that runs as a server. It listens to incoming connections, runs whatever it is that needs to be executed, and returns the results. This server should also be secure and authenticated (just imagine what would happen if anyone could run arbitrary scripts on your machine just by knowing your ip address).

On Linux, this is normally done using [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). For windows, what you need is something like [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) which

> "lets you execute processes on other systems, complete with full
>   interactivity for console applications, without having to manually
>   install client software"